# Pythonで日本語間の空白削除

Tags: python, python3

以前JavaScriptで同様の質問をさせて頂きましたが、Pythonではどのような記述になるのでしょうか？

・言語
Python(Python3)

・したいこと
日本語と英語が混じった文字列中の、日本語で挟まれた空白だけを除去したいです

・例
入力：田中 太郎 is Japanese boy.という 例文があります。
出力：田中太郎 is Japanese boy.という例文があります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

投稿者です。
自分で解決しましたので、ここに回答を書かせて頂きます。失礼しました。

```
import re
str ="田中 太郎 is Japanese boy.という 例文があります。"
result = re.sub('([あ-んア-ン一-鿐ー])\s+((?=[あ-んア-ン一-鿐ー]))',r'\1\2', str)

print(str)
print(result)
```

実行結果

```
田中 太郎 is Japanese boy.という 例文があります。
田中太郎 is Japanese boy.という例文があります。
```